# Can't delete NSOrderedSet from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have one to many relationship in my coredata model. For each News object I have many details object.

```
class Job: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var count: NSNumber
@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var startDate: NSDate
@NSManaged var finishDate: NSDate
@NSManaged var expected: NSDate
@NSManaged var isFinished: NSNumber
@NSManaged var sender: String
@NSManaged var receiver: String
@NSManaged var details: NSOrderedSet

}

class JobDetail: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var message: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var location: String
@NSManaged var status: NSNumber
@NSManaged var parent: Job

}
```

So, how can I remove all details from Job? My current approach is to delete Job itself and create it again which is slower.

I have tried to delete with,

```
context?.deletedObjects(myJob.detail)
```

but it didn’t work. It says

> '(@lvalue NSOrderedSet) -> _' is not identical to 'Set'

Comment: What didn't work? Are you getting any errors? Did you check `context` wasn't `nil`?

Comment: Do you want to delete all objects in `details` from database or just break the relationship?

Comment: I want to delete all objects from details. Since I get new details from network I want to remove old completely from database, and attach fresh ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you mixed-up `deleteObject()` with `deletedObjects()`.

`deletedObjects()` is a method to get a list of all managed objects which
have been *marked for deletion* in the managed object context. What you have to call is `deleteObject()`
for each object. Something like (not compiler-checked):

```
for detail in myJob.details {
   context.deleteObject(detail)
}
```

Comment: ```context.deleteObject(detail as! JobDetail)``` worked. I wish there could be a single delete function for deleting it. Oh well. Thanks.